# Making sublists in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to create sublists within lists so that I can call on the sum function to have all the value (each sublists must have the same length). I tried using the range function with having the start and end as variable, and after each variable, add up to the start and end.

```
temp1 = list()
distance = list()
start = 0
end = 3
distance_list = [1.4.5,5,3,5,4,5,8]
for a in range(3):
    for b in range(start,end):
        temp1.append(distance_list[b]
        distance.append(temp1)
        start += 3
        end += 3
```

Here, the expected result is to simply be able to create a list that is like

```
distance = [[1,4,5],[5,3,5],[4,5,8]]
```

However, the result that I got is the fact that the number b got extremely large. 
What are some suggestion to tackle this problem?

Comment: Can you post your entire code? You have errors in your question and variables that are undefined.

Comment: `[distance_list[n:n+3] for n in range(0, len(distance_list), 3)]`

Answer (score 1):

```
dis = [1,4,5,5,3,5,4,5,8]

sol = [dis[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(dis),3)]

print(sol)
```

output

```
[[1, 4, 5], [5, 3, 5], [4, 5, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the purpose

```
def split_list_to_multiple(input_vals, num_of_splits=5):
    """Splits a list into given number of splits, lists."""
    k, m = divmod(len(input_vals), num_of_splits)
    return (input_vals[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(num_of_splits))
```

Comment: it's better if code is written for human, make it simple